# How do I turn off alt-` for switching between application windows?  

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

How do I turn off alt-` in unity for switching between application windows?

I've already disabled using alt to show the hud, and I've disabled the unity switcher in favor of the static switcher.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the System Settings -> Keyboard, Shortcut tab. Look for your shortcut and disable it.
You can look at the answer from that post : [How to disable Ctrl+Q system wide](https://askubuntu.com/q/201227/94635) for a more detailed answer.